# In the middle of "Too many files open" mess

Tags: files, linux-kernel, ulimit, kernel-parameters

I am in the middle of "file limit" mess and I am not sure what to do.

I am sure restarting the system will help for a while. However, could someone **point me in the right direction for tools to help diagnose this** and get to the bottom of the issue here?

After using my system without a restart for a couple week, a few things start to bother me:

- the system becomes noticeably sluggish,
- some programs crash for no apparent reason or logs: for example, if I am running Wezterm - Google Chrome fails to start,
- or Google Chrome is running - then Wezterm is failing to start.

It has been going on for many months now, and I am failing to understand what is causing this.

This time I decided to try and run Wezterm from another terminal emulator to see if it spills any errors in the stdout. It did. Apparently, I am hitting a limit of open file descriptors.

I've checked and re-checked current limits, and attempted to increase it per random advise from the internet. No luck. I don't understand why the number of file description is not enough for Wezterm to start.

[image]

To make matters more confusing, my attempt to see the number of currently open files per process shows this:

```
lsof | awk '{ print $1 " " $2; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -15
[...]
lsof: no pwd entry for UID 65535
lsof: no pwd entry for UID 65535
  72450 plasmashe 610475
  39294 krunner 623883
  27808 telegram- 2383506
  22572 chrome 2167881
  21600 chrome 2167924
  21344 slack 616893
  20987 plasma-di 2394216
  17050 kwin_x11 610405
  12606 zeal 610569
   8732 slack 616960
   8692 1password 2364911
   7766 konsole 2403669
   7480 spectacle 1976672
   7452 xdg-deskt 610370
   4456 kded5 610402
```

The first column is supposedly the number of file descriptors by a process. How come processes need that files open? Also: there's no way this aligns with an upper bound of 50k file descriptors. Super confused now.

Trivia:

- sysctl:

  ```
  sysctl --all | grep file-max
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.protected_fifos'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.protected_hardlinks'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.protected_regular'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.protected_symlinks'
  fs.file-max = 9223372036854775807
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.apparmor_display_secid_mode'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.cad_pid'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_apparmor_policy'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.usermodehelper.bset'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.usermodehelper.inheritable'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.core.bpf_jit_harden'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.core.bpf_jit_kallsyms'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.core.bpf_jit_limit'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen_key'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.br-77aecafe7c63.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.br-faf1bfa0fcca.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.docker0.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0f1.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.wlp3s0.stable_secret'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.mmap_rnd_bits'
  sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.mmap_rnd_compat_bits'
  ```

  sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.stat_refresh'
- Kernel version:

  ```
  uname -a
  Linux eugene-pc 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- OS version:

  ```
  lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
  Release:        22.04
  Codename:       jammy
  ```

Comment: Please include the output of `sysctl | grep file-max` and `ulimit -n`

Comment: @Panki included in a "Trivia" section. Btw, in the first half of the screenshot I do a similar exercise all existing places for limits, that I am aware of.